# List unification in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am a Prolog newbie with very simple question regarding list unification.

If `[a,b,c]` unifies with `[a|T]` resulting in `T=[b,c]`

why doesn't `[a,b,c]` unify with `[b|T]`?

Comment: `a` and `b` are atoms, not variables. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To unify means, in a very simplified way, to match patterns. When you unify:

```
[a, b, c] = [a | T]
```

you're saying, in the right side, that the first list contains an element `a` followed by a tail `T`. Now, if you say:

```
[a, b, c] = [b | T]
```

the previous statement does not apply, since you do not have, on the left side, a list that begins with `a` and is followed by a tail-list `T`, i.e., the `[a, b, c]` does not *unify* with the list `[b | T]`.

Answer (score 3):

Because `b` is not the *head* of the list `[a,b,c]`. Prolog list notation is *syntactic sugar* over a very simple structure.

- The empty list is represented as the atom `[]`.
- Non-empty lists (that is, list of length 1 or more) are represented as a single `./2` structure (`.(A,B)`) where the first (leftmost) argument to the structure is the *head* (first item) of the list and the second (rightmost) argument is the *tail* (the list that is the remainder of the list of the list, which may be either the empty list or — recursively — another non-empty list. So

  - A list of one item, `[a]`, is represented internally as this prolog term:

    ```
    .(a,[]).
    ```
  - A list of two items, `[a,b]` is represented internally as you might expect:

    ```
    .(a,.(b,[]))
    ```
  - A list of three items, `[a,b,c]` is represented in the same way:

    ```
    .(a,.(b,.(c,[])))
    ```

  And so on.

The vertical bar (`|`) operator in prolog list notation, used to divide a list into its *head* and *tail*, is likewise syntactic sugar for the same `./2` structure. The term

```
[H|T]
```

is *exactly* identical to

```
.(H,T)
```

And an expressions like

```
[A,B|Rest]
[A,B,C|Rest]
```

are, respectively, identical to

```
.(A,.(B,Rest))
.(A,.(B,.(C,Rest)))
```

Given all that, it should be pretty obvious why an expression like

```
[a,b,c] = [b|T]
```

fails, because it's **exactly identical** to:

```
.(a,.(b,.(c,[]))) = .(b,T)
```

The first elements of each side, respectively `a` and `b` are different and so the unification fails.